# How to increment a counter for a while loop within the loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, post-increment, postfix-operator

I have a feeling I'm gonna feel really stupid here, but I'm just learning about using `++` and `--` to increment and decrements variables for while loops, and was wondering why this piece of code works and why this doesn't?

Bad code:

```
int ctr = 0;
while (ctr < 10)
  printf("%d",ctr);
  ctr=ctr+1;
```

The bad code outputs zeros indefinitely.

Working code:

```
int ctr=0;
while (ctr++ < 10)
    printf("%d",ctr);
```

The idea is for the output to be 012345678910 but even in the working code, it starts at 1 and goes to 10, instead of starting at 0. Even though the initial value of ctr is 0.

Comment: C doesn't care about your whitespace and manual indentation. You needs some `{}`.

Comment: C is not Python.  Indentation doesn't matter in C — at least, not to the compiler, but humans trying to read your code care about it.

Comment: Just to add to what @JonathanLeffler said, compiler will read and translate your code anyway, it's just humans who will abandon your code.

Comment: Your Bad code is missing curly braces:

int ctr = 0;
while (ctr < 10){
  printf("%d",ctr);
  ctr=ctr+1;}
Now print satement and the ctr increment statement would be within scope of while loop, and you will get correc value of ctr ie;  0 to 9.

your Working code:

int ctr=0;
while (ctr++ < 10) {
    printf("%d",ctr);}  here you are getting output for ctr from 1 to 9 because ctr++ is incrementing ctr to ctr+1 ie; 0+1 = 1, and then printing.  if you want it to be printed starting from  0 to 9, use the first approah, just remember to add curly brace to decide the scope of while

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case

```
while (ctr < 10)
  printf("%d",ctr);
  ctr=ctr+1;
```

the `while` loop body is considered *only* the `printf()` statement. `ctr=ctr+1;` is not part of the loop body. So you have an unchanged variable in loop condition check, which makes it infinite loop.

You need to enclose both the statements in a block scope, using `{}` so that both the statements become part of the loop body. Something like

```
while (ctr < 10) {
  printf("%d",ctr);
  ctr=ctr+1;
}
```

will do.

---

In the second case

```
int ctr=0;
while (ctr++ < 10)
    printf("%d",ctr);
```

`ctr` is already incremented as the side effect of the postfix increment operator, in the `while` condition checking expression. Thus, while printing the value, the already incremented value is being printed.

Comment: @KeineLust Right, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, indeed.

```
int ctr = 0;
while (ctr < 10)
  printf("%d",ctr);
  ctr=ctr+1;
```

In this first piece of code, in spite of the indentation, your `while` is only involving `printf("%d",ctr);`, because there is no block making `ctr=ctr+1;` belong to the `while`.

It could be written:

```
int ctr = 0;
while (ctr < 10)
  printf("%d",ctr);
ctr=ctr+1;     // This is not in the loop, even with the previous indentation.
```

There is no increment to `ctr` in this loop and then it will run forever printing zeros.

In this second piece of code

```
int ctr=0;
while (ctr++ < 10)
    printf("%d",ctr);
```

you do increment `ctr` every pass and it will work fine.

If you want to make the first loop work, write it like this:

```
int ctr = 0;
while (ctr < 10) {
  printf("%d",ctr);
  ctr=ctr+1;
}
```

Now `ctr=ctr+1;` is really inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score -3):

```
int ctr = 0;
while (ctr++ <= 10)
{ 
    printf("%d",ctr-1);
}
```

Output to be `012345678910`.

Comment: Output? Where are you printing something in this code?

Comment: `var test` is invalid C.  You've not printed anything?

Comment: The edited code is at least C.  However, it is aconventional (and unnecessary) to use `ctr - 1` in the printing.  You could apply the `++` in the call to `printf()` — as in `printf("%d", ctr++);` — and omit it from the `while` condition.  The output includes a leading zero as requested — but the sample output didn't include that originally.  Good answers on SO tend to have more explanation of why the fix is appropriate and why the original was broken.